# FastICA shapes not aligned with normal values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decomposition

I want to use FastICA on my datas with shapes (8, 11513856). (8 samples of size 11513856 each).
Using PCA works just fine :

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, FastICA
pca = PCA(n_components=5, whiten=False)
reduced = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

But when I use the exact same datas on FastICA :

```
ica = FastICA(n_components=5, whiten=False)
reduced = ica.fit_transform(X)
```

I got the error :

> ValueError: shapes (8,8) and (11513856,8) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 11513856 (dim 0)

The error occurs at the ica.fit line.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I could see other persons with the same problem as me but it seems like it was an error in the source code of sklearn.

Edit 1 : Using `whiten=True` doesn't throw any error but my google colab session crashes.

Comment: So you have 8 samples? And each sample has 11513856 features that was measured? Usually it is the opposite. Usually you have more features than samples.

Comment: @gnodab I know, but I do have 8 samples. It's high quality audios and working on more samples makes google colab crashes...

Comment: So you have 8 microphones?

Comment: @gnodab No I have 2 microphones. Each sample is a different part of an original audio.  You mean each sample should be a different microphone's entry ?

Comment: The canonical example of using [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) is [blind source separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_separation). In the case of the [coctail party problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect), you would treat each microphone as a different *feature* that is measured. The samples would be dependents on the length of time. I don't know your use case. I hope this helps. To get the code to run, you just need `X.T`. But I don't know if the results will make sense, because I'm not sure what the goal is. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment ! I want to do a blind source separation, but I have 2 microphones, and around 8 sources of sounds. Apparently, I can't have more than 2 components on FastICA (because I have 2 microphones). Maybe I shouldn't use FastICA for what I want ?

Comment: You can still try. I think ICA is your best option. Just keep in mind that the problem is ill formed when you have more sources than microphones. So it may not work as well as some of the examples demonstrate